# 40gb ide hard drive shows only 512b of space and cannot be initialized

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

for quite some time I have had a 40gb IDE hard drive which has worked flawlessly at least until now. Only last week the hard drive accidentally fell from the top of my full tower computer case. and since then has stopped working and even showing up as a hard drive connected to the computer. I tried taking it to a local shop wherein the person told me that IDE was an age old standard and hence the disk would be hard to even recover let alone repair. So i took it to myself to try some tinkering and finally got the hard drive to at least show up as a USB device by moving the IDE-USB connector pins 2 pins towards the right. However now the drive shows only 512 bytes of space in place of 40gb and still disk management says that disk has not been initialized (error) and when I try to initialize it it says error Data redundancy check failed :(. Any ways to recover data would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pay someone else to do it.  DriveSavers and many other data recovery companies can if your willing to pay recover your data.

Comment: Also buy an SSD replace this ancient drive, and a get drive you can drop without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop messing with it. Every poor guess you make trying to DIY exacerbates the situation & makes the possibility of recovery smaller.
2. Take it to a data recovery specialist. They are expensive & make no guarantees.
3. Make sure you have a backup strategy. It's cheaper & safer in the long run than waiting til something breaks & having to rely on 2.

Comment: The guy I talked tells me about another person who may be able to repair it but the other dude gives no guarantees about data,time and money

Comment: I wouldn't entrust this task to anyone who answers to the title of "dude". You need a professional data recovery company. A "dude" will likely wreck it for good.